# Проблема с подключением к БД MySql из приложения Delphi

Tags: delphi, база-данных, mysql

Подключаюсь через DbExpress к удаленной БД (MYSQL) все время выдает ошибку

> `invalid username/password`

хотя логин и пароль правильные. В чем может быть проблема? На локальном сервере все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть в том, что эти логин и пароль разрешены только на локальной машине (на той, где крутится СУБД), например user@localhost.

Нужно убедиться, что учетная запись допускает подключения извне.

Comment: А каким образом можно убедиться?

Comment: Зайти в админку или подключиться по ssh. Посмотрите какие пользователи у вас в таблице `mysql.user`.

- `someuser@localhost` будет работать только локально.
- `someuser@"%"` будет работать отовсюду.

Comment: Из PHP скрипта, расположенном на этом же хостинге  подключение локально?

Comment: Как правило, да. Вообще, когда СУБД шибко удаленная, обычно не практикуют подключение к ней напрямую. В идеале, СУБД вообще не должно торчать наружу. Вместо этого делают трехзвенную систему: 

СУБД <==> Сервер <==> Клиент

При этом сервер находится в той же сети (или даже на той же), что и СУБД. Связи между сервером и клиентом можно организовать, например, по HTTP (XML, JSON).

Comment: Я настроил подключение к MySQL базе извне, но опять та же самая ошибка. В чем дело ?

Comment: Как вы его настроили?